# Knet payment gateway for PHP

Tags: php, payment-gateway

I am looking to integrate Knet payment gateway in PHP, but they have provided API for .NET, JSP and Python only.

Can anyone please help me and provide any idea how to integrate the KNET in PHP.

Comment: I can't find anything about a gateway for KNET, but if you have the documentation, it is definitely feasible.  I am assuming they use SOAP or XML to transfer data.  You probably need a key, curl to the api, submit data, then retrieve the data.  SOAP/XML data structure will be the same on .Net, JSP, and Python.

Comment: Here i have uploaded the document of Knet - https://docs.google.com/open?id=0B4lCwSRTKNwSMDljYzU3MzUtZjkxYy00NTViLWE2NzgtNDA0MWIxZWY5ZTJl

Comment: They are not using SOAP or XMl to transfer the Data.

Comment: Yeah I see that... I don't know, I don't have the sample code to look at, so I can't tell exactly how it is transferred.  Maybe someone else will have a first hand knowledge with this.

Comment: please provide me link of API documentation of KNET

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Update**

KNET now officially supports PHP natively. You can browse their official client at [this github repo](https://github.com/GDGKuwait/knet-php-demo).

Disclaimer: The above repository is maintained by the Google Developer's Group Kuwait chapter and is not associated with KNET. However, the code uploaded is what KNET provides to their clients.

Warning: The KNET client only supports debit transactions, it does not support credit card transactions, which are supported by the commerce gateway.

---

KNET's uses ACI's [commerce gateway](http://aciworldwide.com/en/Products-and-services/Products/ACI-Commerce-Gateway.aspx) for payment processing and their supported solution for PHP is to use the [PHP-java bridge](http://php-java-bridge.sourceforge.net/pjb/).

There are other options as well, but none are officially supported by KNET, however they all work:

1. [Python implementation](https://github.com/burhankhalid/e24paymentpipe) (disclaimer: I wrote this)
2. [Ruby implementation](https://github.com/aalhamad/e24paymentpipe)

A Google search for [`e24paymentpipe php`](http://www.google.com/search?q=e24paymentpipe+php) should get you going.

Comment: So we want to do PHP-JAVA bridge to implement in PHP? Is there any other ways or any extensions...

Comment: I would avoid the PHP-Java bridge at all costs. I had a project where I had to use it and it caused a lot more pain than it was worth.

Comment: I am writing a Ruby wrapper for this. Just wanted to know why do we need  https://github.com/aalhamad/e24paymentpipe/blob/master/lib/e24paymentpipe/message.rb#L18 .. We need to do Payment initialization, right? Why need to do transacion initialization ?

Comment: Any support for ios platform

Answer (score 4):

You can use this [php implementation on github](https://github.com/TigerWolf/e24PaymentPipe-php) that works with php 5.3.

See credits on the git readme for more information.

Comment: Off-topic: it would be nice if you would add the author(s) credits into the PHP file as well. Others are copying it over and then it's not clear, e.g. https://sites.google.com/site/akshayjindal1990/downloads - you could also leave your github URL inside.