# How to integrate KNET payment gateway with php

Tags: java, php, payment-gateway

How can I integrate the KNET payment gateway with PHP? The gateway id only works with Java and .NET.

Comment: Dupe: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8600230/knet-payment-gateway-for-php

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to Install PHP / Java Bridge for it. Then You have to copy your jar file which is given by your payment gateway to /WEB-INF/Lib. Then call that java class in your PHP.

Enjoy.

Comment: what about ios ?

Answer (score 4):

You can use this [php implementation on github](https://github.com/TigerWolf/e24PaymentPipe-php) that works with php 5.3.

See credits on the git readme for more information.

Comment: yes i read all the document but thanks for response by the way i have integrated KNET payment gateway in my site and its working fine .

Comment: @Pritesh Mahajan from where you got API information, can you please share this info here.

Comment: @mark did you done KNET payment integration.

Comment: I I have not but I know the procedure, We need KNET development kit for proceed for specific language.They will provide us payment info kit after subscribing their service  and its not free.

Comment: What about ios ?

Comment: This would not normally be done on a phone and you would get an smart phone app to do this via an API.