# KNET payment gateway "failed Unable to open resource" Error in Prestashop

Tags: prestashop, prestashop-1.6

I am doing integration of Knet payment gateway in Prestashop for my client, but i can't find what is the solution for "failed Unable to open resource" ?

i also updated "Alias" parameter...which i get from client...but still its not woking..

Can anyone please help me and provide any idea how to integrate the KNET in Prestashop.

Below is my code snippest:

i always get error like "failed Unable to open resource"

```
$total = Context::getContext()->cart->getOrderTotal(true);

    //random number generation
    $x = 3; // Amount of digits
    $min = pow(10,$x);
    $max = (pow(10,$x+1)-1);
    $randomvalue = rand($min, $max);


    if(Configuration::get('_Knet_TESTMODE')){


    require_once "e24PaymentPipe.inc.php" ;
    $Pipe = new e24PaymentPipe;
    $Pipe->setAction(1);
    $Pipe->setCurrency(414);
    $Pipe->setLanguage("ENG"); //change it to "ARA" for arabic language
    $Pipe->setResponseURL('https://www.knetpaytest.com.kw/php/response.php'); // set your respone page URL
    $Pipe->setErrorURL('https://www.knetpaytest.com.kw/php/error.php'); //set your error page URL
    $Pipe->setAmt($total); //set the amount for the transaction
   $Pipe->setResourcePath('http://'.$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'].$this->_path.'resource/'); //change the path where your resource file is

    $Pipe->setAlias("******"); //set your alias name here
    $Pipe->setTrackId($randomvalue);//generate the random number here

    $Pipe->setUdf1("UDF 1"); //set User defined value
    $Pipe->setUdf2("UDF 2"); //set User defined value   
    $Pipe->setUdf3("UDF 3"); //set User defined value
    $Pipe->setUdf4("UDF 4"); //set User defined value
    $Pipe->setUdf5("UDF 5"); //set User defined value

    $Pipe->performPaymentInitialization();

    if (strlen($Pipe->getErrorMsg()) > 0) { 
        echo $Pipe->getErrorMsg();
    }
```

Comment: Did you find the solution?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Knet payment gateway for PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8600230/knet-payment-gateway-for-php)

Answer (score 0):

> install ziparchive extesnsion in your wamp then it will start working.